# How run executable .jar file with Python & subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have been running the batch file before. ( with Python )

The batch file contents are like this

```
@echo off
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Djava.file.encoding=UTF-8 -jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m C:\val\val.jar --basedir C:\val --filetype shp --cidx 5 --layerdefpath C:\val\임상도layer.json --valoptpath C:\val\임상도option.json --objfilepath C:\val\50000.zip --crs EPSG:5186

pause>nul
```

Now I want to run the jar file directly, not the batch file.

But It is not work.

```
query = '"%JAVA_HOME/bin/java"' + ' -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Djava.file.encoding=UTF-8 -jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m C:/val/val.jar --basedir C:/val --filetype shp --cidx %s --layerdefpath %s --valoptpath %s --objfilepath %s --crs EPSG:5186 \npause>nul' % (cidx, self.dockwidget.path1.text(),self.dockwidget.path2.text(),self.dockwidget.path3.text())

process = subprocess.Popen(
    query,
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

The query of param is same with batch file contents.

I don't know what is problem.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most immediate problem seems to be a typo assuming your latter code block is an accurate copy/paste. Namely, `%JAVA_HOME` would need to be `%JAVA_HOME%` to be interpreted as variable by the shell called.

However, I'd make few more hopefully useful suggestions. The `\npause>nul` actually doesn't do anything (and even if it did, it would seem to make more sense to handle waiting for user input in the python script itself).

When you make `subprocess.Popen` call and perform output redirection into `subprocess.PIPE`, you likely want to also retrieve this output and follow that line with `(out, err) = process.communicate()`.

The last but not least, instead of concatenating and formatting string and relying on the shell to parse it back into desired arguments, I would suggest looking into passing an arguments vector instead. I.e. define `query` as:

```
query = [os.path.join(os.environ["JAVA_HOME"], "bin/java"),
         "-Dfile.encoding=utf-8", "-Djava.file.encoding=UTF-8",
         "-jar", "-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m", "C:/val/val.jar",
         "--basedir", "C:/val", "--filetype", "shp", "--cidx", cidx,
         "--layerdefpath", self.dockwidget.path1.text(),
         "--valoptpath", self.dockwidget.path2.text(),
         "--objfilepath", self.dockwidget.path3.text(),
         "--crs", "EPSG:5186"]
```

and drop the `shell=True` keyword argument then.